# Keep form data inside the field after submission using php

Tags: php, forms, textarea

I am using below code for a html form.(it has two forms) I am able to keep the textarea field after the first and second form submission. but issue I am facing here is the dropdown menu selection.

Code:

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="emcsaninfo-symcli-main">
    <form  id="form1" name="form1" action=" " method="post" > 



        <div class="input">Your Name</div>
        <div class="response"><span><input  class="textbox" id="myname" name="myname" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['myname'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['myname']); }?>" /></span> </div>


        <div class="input">Your Place</div>
        <div class="response"><span><input  class="textbox" id="myplace" name="myplace" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['myplace'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['myplace']); }?>" /></span> </div>

        <div class="input-quest">Graduation Status</div>
        <div class="input-resp"><select id="graduation" name="graduation" OnChange="CMT();"><option class="dropdown-options">Graduate</option><option class="dropdown-options">Non Graduate</option></select></div>

<div class="submit">
        <input  id="first_submit" type="submit"  name="first_submit" value="first_submit" />
</div>

</form>


<?php

if(!empty($_POST['myname']) && !empty($_POST['myplace']) || !empty($_POST['output_textarea'] ) )
{

$myname = $_POST['myname'];
$myplace = $_POST['myplace'];
$graduation = $_POST['graduation'];

?>


<form  id="form2" name="form2" action=" " method="post" >
<textarea onclick="this.select()" name="output_textarea" id="output_textarea" cols="100" rows="25" readonly value="<?php if(isset($_POST['output_textarea'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['output_textarea']); }?>">


<?php

echo "My name is $myname and I am from $myplace, and I am $graduation";

?>

</textarea>

<input  id="submit1" type="submit"  name="name_field" value="submit1" />
<input  id="submit2" type="submit"  name="place_field" value="submit2" />

<input  id="myname_hidden" name="myname" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['myname'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['myname']); }?>"/>
<input  id="myplace_hidden" name="myplace" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['myplace'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['myplace']); }?>" />
<input  id="graduation_hidden" name="graduation" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['graduation'])) { $graduation = $_POST['graduation']; }?>" />
</form> 

<?php

function name()
{
    echo $_POST["output_textarea"];
}
if(isset($_POST['name_field']))
{
   name();
} 



function place()
{
    echo $_POST["output_textarea"];
}
if(isset($_POST['place_field']))
{
   place();
} 

}

?>


</div>      

</html>
</body>
```

For example if I put `name = John`, `place : UK` and selecting graduation status as `graduate`, it will will give me first form output as in my `output textarea`

```
My name is John and I am from UK, and I am Graduate
```

I have two seperate submit button for second form, using that I am doing some other function with help of the `output textarea`
If I press any of the second button,I m able to keep entries my name and place area, but it not keeping the dropdown selection. so it will only display like after submitting `submit1` or `submit2`

```
My name is John and I am from UK, and I am
```

Here,

1. How can I keep the the dropdown selection also with the output text area
2. Will I able to show only the output_textarea content after second form submission without keeping the first form data ?

[**PHP FIDDLE**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/r5h-anw)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error in logic in the hidden input for the "graduate" element.
This is what you have at lines 53-55. Line 55 doesn't have an echo instead it has an `$graduation = $_POST['graduation'];` which won't help you:

```
<input  id="myname_hidden" name="myname" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['myname'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['myname']); }?>"/>
<input  id="myplace_hidden" name="myplace" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['myplace'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['myplace']); }?>" />
<input  id="graduation_hidden" name="graduation" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['graduation'])) { $graduation = $_POST['graduation']; }?>" />
```

instead of that, this code should work:

```
<input  id="myname_hidden" name="myname" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['myname'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['myname']); }?>"/>
<input  id="myplace_hidden" name="myplace" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['myplace'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['myplace']); }?>" />
<input  id="graduation_hidden" name="graduation" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['graduation'])) { echo htmlentities($_POST['graduation']); }?>" />
```